# Browser prompts for user & password when already signed in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm facing a very strange problem here. I am using .NET MV5 to build a simple application where I use Identity to authenticate users through simple accounts. Everything is fine on localhost but when I published the site on IIS, there is an action in a controller that even though I am already authenticated, the browser prompts with a window asking for a valid user & password.. I write the information again but no matter what I do, the browser keeps asking for the same information and the View never gets displayed.

I only have a single role and the user has it active. The controller class is protected through the [Authorize] annotation without role validation.

Any ideas?? I can share more information if it is needed..

Comment: Isn't that Windows Authentication? Ensure that it is not enabled on IIS.

Comment: Have you tried running the release in local host? just in case there is something wrong in the release config

Comment: When you say authenticate through simple accounts, is that windows auth, basic auth?  If you go to IIS > authentication option for the app, what options are enabled?

Comment: It is not Windows Auth, they are identity accounts that are stored on the application's database.

Comment: @BrianMains the only option enabled is Anonymous Authentication.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Everything runs fine on localhost. All controllers are protected when I am not signed in and when I sign in the controller displays fine without prompt

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer...

It turns out that indeed the window that asks for a user & password was asking for Windows Authentication as some of you guys were suggesting, which was strange considering the MVC app wasn't even using it. I wrote an admin server account and the page redirected to somewhere else.

The controller I was trying to reach was /Reports/TeacherEarnings and redirected to Reports/browse. The IIS somehow interpreted that I was trying to reach the SQL Reporting Services in the same server and asked for Windows Authentication, overriding the MVC app Controller...

Hope this helps someone in the future.